# css3/sass little weird units of rem? ( css3 of rem not working?)

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass

```js
var scale = 1 / window.devicePixelRatio;

document.querySelector('meta[name="viewport"]').setAttribute('content', 'initial-scale=' + scale + ', maximum-scale=' + scale + ', minimum-scale=' + scale + ', user-scalable=no');

document.documentElement.style.fontSize = document.documentElement.clientWidth / 10 + 'px';
```

```css
//scss


$baseFontSize : 75;
@function r( $px ){
 @return $px/$baseFontSize + rem;
}

body {
 font-family: Roboto-Regular, Helvetica, STHeiTi, sans-serif;
 line-height: 1.2;
}
.text{
 font-size: r(20);
}
.s_a{
 text-align: center;
 font-size: r(10);
}
.s_b{
 font-size: r(20);
}
.s_c{
 font-size: r(28);
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0" name="viewport">
  <title>index</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class='text'>Sed sit amet sem nec nisi sodales laoreet at et</div>

  <div class="s_a">New juanpi special</div>
  <p class="s_b">75% off·shipping·Limited quantity</p>
  <div class="s_c"><a href="baidu.com">See more details on the App</a>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

class to 'text' elements set 'font-size: r (30);' and 'font-size: r (20);' after other page elements fontSize performance is completely different, and why?

This also occurs if you delete the class is 's_c' element inside the 'a' label.

I need your help! :(

Comment: I think you're doing the operation backwards: `@function r( $px ){
 @return $baseFontSize/$px + rem;`
}

Comment: No, I think we should wrap the browser font redraw triggered caused

Comment: you are right, the operation is ok but you are using a $baseFontSize  too high and the values you get are very low and there are no differences between the texts that reach their minimum size